# How to segregate the Buddypress member page on multisite?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, multisite

I have a BuddyPress social networks in a multi network WordPress install (WordPress multisite), thanks to LH Buddypress Multi Network plugin.

How can I prevent people from accessing to a profile page from another blog?

For example :
`teacherSite`, `teacherUser`
`studentSite`, `studentUser`

I have restricted access to site for non-member.
`teacherUser` can only connect on `teacherSite`.
And he can’t see in the directory other users from others blogs.

If `studentUser` knows the `teacherUser` username or if he finds or tests…

He can go to:

> studentSite.domain.com/members/teacherUser/

And he can see the profile of `teacherUser` even though `teacherUser` is not linked to `studentSite`.

Fortunately, there is no information (because everything else is well segregated) except the name and the gravatar.

But he can still make a connection request or send him a private message!
`teacherUser` will not see any notification on `teacherSite`. But he will potentially receive an email which will redirect him to `studentSite` without being able to connect to it.

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing BuddyPress has somewhat the same user management system as WordPress.

We could compare the current user role with the queried user role. If they're different, we block and redirect.

```php
<?php

/**
 * Compare the queried user role with the current user role.
 * If both don't match restrict profile access and redirect to current user profile.
 * 
 * Case exceptions: 
 * - IF the current user IS the queried user. 
 * - IF the current user IS an Admin or Super-Admin.
 */
add_action( 'wp', function() {

    if ( is_author() && get_queried_object() instanceof \WP_User ) {

        if ( reset( get_queried_object()->roles ) === reset( wp_get_current_user()->roles ) || get_current_user_id() === get_queried_object_id() || current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) { // ... @see https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#capability-vs-role-table

            return;

        } else {

            header( 'Refresh: 2; ' . esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_current_user_id() ) ) );

            $args = array(
                'back_link' => true,
            );

            wp_die( "Error, Restricted access. You're not allowed to view this profile.", 'Error, Restricted access', $args );

        };

    };

} );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it doesn't work.